# Merging sublists in a list according to a keyword

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have list of lists looking like this:

```
 [['\ufeff'],
 ['<dialog #1 (338)>'],
 ['02:48\tVšechny větrací otvory nesmí být zakryty'],
 ['02:50\tV přihrádkách na potraviny'],
 ['02:52\tNepoškoďte potrubní vedení chladícího média'],
 ['02:56\tPři definitivním postavení zařízení'],
 ['02:56\tPři konečném postavení zařízení'],
 ['02:57\tPři konečném postavení'],
 ['02:57\tPři konečném postavení'],
 ['02:58\tdefinitivním postavení'],
 ['02:58\tdefinitivním postavení'],
 ...........and so on.
```

See that "dialog" word on line 2? It repeats itself throughout the file tens of thousands of times. I would like to merge all sublists from the first sublist containing the word "dialog" to the last sublist that does not contain that word. So I end up with sublists containing just one "dialog" word at the beginning.

It might also be possible (and more convenient) to change the way I import those txt files. I use this code:

```
dialogues1 = []
with open('dialogy1.txt', encoding="utf-8") as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        dialogues1.append(line.splitlines())
```

Maybe there is a different way of loading the file that would give me the same result. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What would be your desired output from the given example?

Comment: `['<dialog #1 (338)>','02:48\tVšechny větrací otvory nesmí být zakryty', '02:50\tV přihrádkách na potraviny', '02:52\tNepoškoďte potrubní vedení chladícího média', '02:56\tPři definitivním postavení zařízení', '02:56\tPři konečném postavení zařízení','02:57\tPři konečném postavení']...` Basically, list of merged sublists where the first string in every sublist contains the phrase with "dialog". Is it more clear?

Comment: Instead of `[['dialog....'],['string'],['string'].......['dialog'],['string'],['string']...]`, I need `[['dialog....','string','string'],['dialog','string','string'...]...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move all of the list with content containing `"dialog"`, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
s = [['\ufeff'], ['<dialog #1 (338)>'], ['02:48\tVšechny větrací otvory nesmí být zakryty'], ['02:50\tV přihrádkách na potraviny'],['02:52\tNepoškoďte potrubní vedení chladícího média'], ['02:56\tPři definitivním postavení zařízení'], ['02:56\tPři konečném postavení zařízení'], ['02:57\tPři konečném postavení'], ['02:57\tPři konečném postavení'], ['02:58\tdefinitivním postavení'], ['02:58\tdefinitivním postavení']]
new_data = sorted([(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s[1:], key=lambda x: bool(re.findall('\<dialog #\d+', x[0]))), key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('\<dialog #\d+', x[0])))], key=lambda x:x, reverse=True)
final_data = list(map(''.join, [c for h in [b for a, b in new_data] for c in h]))
```

Output:

```
['<dialog #1 (338)>', '02:48\tV\xc5\xa1echny v\xc4\x9btrac\xc3\xad otvory nesm\xc3\xad b\xc3\xbdt zakryty', '02:50\tV p\xc5\x99ihr\xc3\xa1dk\xc3\xa1ch na potraviny', '02:52\tNepo\xc5\xa1ko\xc4\x8fte potrubn\xc3\xad veden\xc3\xad chlad\xc3\xadc\xc3\xadho m\xc3\xa9dia', '02:56\tP\xc5\x99i definitivn\xc3\xadm postaven\xc3\xad za\xc5\x99\xc3\xadzen\xc3\xad', '02:56\tP\xc5\x99i kone\xc4\x8dn\xc3\xa9m postaven\xc3\xad za\xc5\x99\xc3\xadzen\xc3\xad', '02:57\tP\xc5\x99i kone\xc4\x8dn\xc3\xa9m postaven\xc3\xad', '02:57\tP\xc5\x99i kone\xc4\x8dn\xc3\xa9m postaven\xc3\xad', '02:58\tdefinitivn\xc3\xadm postaven\xc3\xad', '02:58\tdefinitivn\xc3\xadm postaven\xc3\xad']
```

Edit: regarding the desired output in your last comment, this solution should work:

```
s = [['\ufeff'], ['<dialog #1 (338)>'], ['02:48\tVšechny větrací otvory nesmí být zakryty'], ['02:50\tV přihrádkách na potraviny'],['02:52\tNepoškoďte potrubní vedení chladícího média'], ['02:56\tPři definitivním postavení zařízení'], ['02:56\tPři konečném postavení zařízení'], ['<dialog #2 (338)>'], ['02:57\tPři konečném postavení'], ['02:57\tPři konečném postavení'], ['02:58\tdefinitivním postavení'], ['02:58\tdefinitivním postavení']]
new_data = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s[1:], key=lambda x:bool(re.findall('\<dialog #\d+', x[0])))]
final_data = [[c for h in new_data[i:i+2] for c in h] for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['<dialog #1 (338)>'], ['02:48\tV\xc5\xa1echny v\xc4\x9btrac\xc3\xad otvory nesm\xc3\xad b\xc3\xbdt zakryty'], ['02:50\tV p\xc5\x99ihr\xc3\xa1dk\xc3\xa1ch na potraviny'], ['02:52\tNepo\xc5\xa1ko\xc4\x8fte potrubn\xc3\xad veden\xc3\xad chlad\xc3\xadc\xc3\xadho m\xc3\xa9dia'], ['02:56\tP\xc5\x99i definitivn\xc3\xadm postaven\xc3\xad za\xc5\x99\xc3\xadzen\xc3\xad'], ['02:56\tP\xc5\x99i kone\xc4\x8dn\xc3\xa9m postaven\xc3\xad za\xc5\x99\xc3\xadzen\xc3\xad']][['<dialog #2 (338)>'], ['02:57\tP\xc5\x99i kone\xc4\x8dn\xc3\xa9m postaven\xc3\xad'], ['02:57\tP\xc5\x99i kone\xc4\x8dn\xc3\xa9m postaven\xc3\xad'], ['02:58\tdefinitivn\xc3\xadm postaven\xc3\xad'], ['02:58\tdefinitivn\xc3\xadm postaven\xc3\xad']]
```